# Axis labels for two variables in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, x-axis

I have a ggplot with three variables: office, level, and gender. The plot should be factored by office and level and shows the levels and gender representation for each office. I have no problem faceting the plot the way I want, but I haven't been able to create x axis text to show the levels in each office -- all that shows up under the x-axis are the office names, which makes it impossible to distinguish among the bars for the different levels (the gender I handle with different colors and isn't a problem, unless someone is colorblind ...). I've edited out the lines for the title, xLab, yLab, etc. to focus on the issue. Grateful for your help!

Here is my data:

```
#A tibble: 20 x 4

   office     level   gender     count
 1 office1      A     Female     3
 2 office1      A     Male       1
 3 office1      B     Female     11
 4 office1      B     Male       9
 5 office1      C     Female     16
 6 office1      C     Male       13
 7 office1      C     Other      2
 8 office1      D     Female     16
 9 office1      D     Male       11
10 office1      D     Female     6
11 office1      D     Male       10
12 office1      D     Other      1
13 office2      A     Male       1
14 office2      A     Female     3
15 office2      B     Male       1
16 office2      B     Female     12
17 office2      B     Male       3
18 office2      B     Female     1
19 office2      D     Male       5
20 office2      D     Male       1
```

And here is my code:

```
myBarChart <- function(data,var1,var2,var3,count,factor1, factor2) {
  
# the following code creates the tibble above when I run the function:
  fields <- c(var1,var2,var3)
  data <- df[ ,fields]
  data[[var1]] <- factor(data[[var1]], levels = factor1)
  data[[var2]] <- factor(data[[var2]], levels = factor2)
  data <- data %>% group_by_at(fields) %>% summarize(count = n()) 
  data <- filter(data,count >= 1)
  data <- na.omit(data) %>% 

# here is the plot code and this is where I need help: 
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x=var1, y=count, fill=var3)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity',width=1.25,position = position_dodge2(padding=0.25,reverse=FALSE,preserve=c("single"))) +
    geom_text(aes(label=count),vjust=-.5,position=position_dodge2(width=1.25,preserve="single"),size=2.5) +
    facet_wrap(var1, strip.position="bottom", scales = "free_x", nrow=1)  +

# I was hoping that the code for strip.text.x would give me the values for var2 (the levels) within each office, but it doesn't.
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(aes(label=data[[var2]]), size=12)) + 
    theme(strip.placement = "outside")

} # end function

# here is how I invoke the function, which runs fine except for the axis labels always reflecting only 'office': 
     myBarChart(data,'office','level','gender',c('office1','office2'),c("A","B","C","D"),'count')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `level` for the x-axis, `count` for the y-axis, facet by `office` and fill by `gender` ?

Something like this:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(level, count, fill = gender)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + 
  facet_wrap(~office, strip.position = "bottom") + 
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. One question: the counts now appear stacked over the center of each column instead of at the top of each bar -- position_dodge(preserve="single") doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Ah, silly old me: forgot to add width to the col and text -- all's well now!